# How to denormalise this data to increase its efficiency in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, denormalization, denormalized

So, I had a PostgreSQL database and I decided to migrate it into MongoDB to increase performance. I ended up building the following model:

[image]

Two main documents, Departamento and Distribuidora. Inside Departamento, I have an array called Funcionarios, which represents the employees that work inside of this department.

Inside Distribuidora, however, the situation is a little more complicated. I have an array of pairs of documents, which represent a product and the city in which they are distributed. This used to be a ternary relationship in my RDBMS, so it's important to know which **pairs** of products and cities are related to a Distribuidora document. If that wasn't enough, every product has an ID that references a Departamento document (departamento_id).

My problem here is that this model lacks in performance optimisation. To do complex queries in elements inside the arrays I have to do repeated unwind operations, and I also have to be pivoting data in order to get information from both collections, so the queries end up being terribly slow.

Therefore, I want to **denormalise** this model as much as I can, preferably in a single document without arrays, but I just can't think of a proper way to do it. Can some please help me in this troublesome task? Thanks a lot in advance.